# Touch for Hidden Menu working on Tablet, not on any iOS Devices

Tags: javascript, android, ios, css, wordpress

Been trying to get my Wordpress Theme to work on iOS for a while now. But there seems to be something missing or I am not getting about how iOS devices work causing me work blindly on this.

I am trying to get a menu (essentially a div) to appear every time another div is tapped. My current setup works on Android, but not on iOS.

```
<script>

var $v = document.getElementsByClassName("midbar")[0];     //the div that activates the appearance of the menu.
var $x = document.getElementsByClassName("menubar")[0];     //the menu that has it's opacity set to 0 at the start.

$v.addEventListener("mouseup", TapEvent, false);     //I used mouseup, touchend works as well.

function TapEvent(event) {

    if ($x.style.opacity == 0) {

        $x.style.height = "300px";
        $x.style.opacity = "1";
        $x.style.overflow-y = "auto";

        }

        else {

        $x.style.height = "0px";
        $x.style.opacity = "0";
        $x.style.overflow-y = "hidden";

        }

    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}

</script>
```

Here is the temporary site: itdctest3.comule.com

The theme converts to mobile mode when the screen size is below 700px. The div that is supposed to reveal the hidden menu is the Black Space to the right of the Site Title at the top of the page.

Any help or even just leads on what to research will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: You have a div with a class <div class="sow-image-container"> I'm guessing that is supposed to have an H in it "show-image-container"

Comment: Hi, the class "sow-image-container" comes from the Site Origin Widgets Bundle (It's actually a plugin im using, that's why it's "sow". Sorry for the confusion).

Comment: Have a look at the plugin css and see if it matches. If not, don't change it but report the bug to the plugin writer who will need to make a new release with the bug fix.

Comment: Hi Carol, the plugin is working fine. They really named it that way (sow == Site Origin Widgets) It is actually quite confusing. My problem is the code posted works on Android, but won't work on any iOS device. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: I guess your still stuck with making a bug report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works, but I still don't understand why what I posted up top worked for Android and not iOS.

All I had to do was wrap the div that activated the other div in a span with a onclick="void(0)" inside it.

Somehow it works now. But I still have to test the hell out of it.

Thank you to all who answered.